# Regex help: Rename and re-arrange filenames using "A Better Finder Rename"

Tags: regex

I have a lot of files that need various tweeks (renaming and rearranging).
Rather then post the whole lot in one go i think it more helpfull to post separately to show the process.

I'm using the replace and rearrange feature in "A Better Finder Rename" but i think the regex code it uses is standard?

A small working example I made as a test used:

```
Pattern: (\d{6})_(\w{4,5})_(.*)_(.*)_(\d{6}).pdf

Substitute: $1_$5_Thankyou_$2_0.pdf
```

But I really need the regex based code for the complete task as set out below.
Turns my brain into knots as i've just started learning about it.

**2 Example file names:** 

137307_DEICR_(F)_Flat 5C Golding House, Claybrook Road_180914.pdf
137430_DEIC_(S)_Flat 14B Golding House, Claybrook Road_180910.pdf
116486_EICR_(S)_Flat 20 Ivy Lane, Osler Road_180920.pdf
116508_EIC_(S)_Flat 26 Ivy Lane, Osler Road_180921.pdf
152270_Flat 23 Ivy Lane Flats, Osler Road OX3 9DT_180921_WTD.pdf
152270_Flat 23 Ivy Lane Flats, Osler Road OX3 9DT_180921_FWR.pdf
147278_DEICR_94_Wellington_Road_160622 (147278-A2Dominion1 ).pdf
147279_DEICR_94_Wellington_Road_160621.pdf (1d7278-A1Dominion1 )

The desired converted filenames are:
137307_180914_Thankyou_EICR_0.pdf
137430_180910_Thankyou_EIC.pdf <—- edited removed "_1"
116486_180920_Thankyou_EICR_1.pdf
116508_180921_Thankyou_EIC.pdf <—-edited, removed "_1"
152270_180921_Thankyou_WTD.pdf
152270_180921_Thankyou_FWR.pdf
147278_160622_Thankyou_EICR.pdf
147279_160621_Thankyou_EICR.pdf

So to break it down 
**TO REPLACE**
"(F)" becomes "_0"
 
"(S)" becomes _1
"DEICR" becomes "EICR"
 
"DEIC" becomes "EIC"
**NOTE: After above steps: "_EIC_1" becomes "_EIC"**
The address (eg "Flat 20 Ivy Lane, Osler Road") becomes a single word (eg "Thankyou")
Any characters at the end of the file in brackets eg "(147278-A2Dominion1 ).pdf" or (.pdf (1d7278-A1Dominion1 ) are deleted.

**TO REARANGE**
"_0" moved to end of file
_1" moved to end of file
"EICR","ECI","WTD","FWR" moved to end of file (not after "_1" or "_01")
6 digit "YYMMDD" Date at end of file moved to the front (after the first 6 digit code)

**DATE FORMAT**
Additionally. Is there a code to change the date format from YYMMDD eg "160622" to DDMMYY "220616" - also as a separate step.

Comment: I don't think, you can do that with a single regex, you will have to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the replacement in one step, because you need to convert `(F)` to `_0` but `(S)` to `_1`, but you can do the replacement in multiple renaming steps, as your filename patterns are distinct from their replacements:

1. Rename all `(F)` files to `_0.pdf`:

Pattern:
    `^(\d{6})_D?([A-Z]+)_\(F\)_(.*)_(\d{6}).pdf$`

Substitute:
`$1_$4_Thankyou_$2_0.pdf`

2. Rename all `(S)`files to `_1.pdf`

Pattern:
    `^(\d{6})_D?([A-Z]+)_\(S\)_(.*)_(\d{6}).pdf$`

Substitute:
`$1_$4_Thankyou_$2_1.pdf`

3. Rename all "non-`D`" files, like above:

Pattern:
    `^(\d{6})_(.*)_(\d{6})_(WTD|FWR).pdf$`

Substitute:
    `$1_$3_Thankyou_$4.pdf`

These three steps should be all you need.

Changing the date format from YYMMDD to DDMMYY is a horrible crime against humanity. Doing that will prevent the file names from sorting chronologically. If you're hell-bent on doing so, the following expressions should do that for the `Thankyou` files:

Pattern: `^(\d+_)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)_(Thankyou_.*).pdf`
Substitute: `$1$4$3$2_$5.pdf`

The regular expression captures the YY, MM and DD parts and rearranges them.

For stripping stuff in parentheses, use the following regular expression:

Pattern: `^(\d{6})_D?([A-Z]+)_(\d+)_(.*)_(\d{6})(\s*\(.*\)\s*)\.pdf$`
Substitute: `$1_$4_Thankyou_$2_0.pdf`

Comment: I'm really sorry - I had a `$5` everywhere where there should have been a `$4`. See https://regex101.com/r/YrMoDN/1 for the test outputs. I've edited my post above.

Comment: HANG ON!! I just changed your first 'Substitute' - whoops too late to sound clever, you already spotted it.

Comment: THis is looking good, thanks so much. My brain has been in knots, this is all new to me.

Comment: Could you possibly add some more steps to cover some remaining file names: the 2 file names given in the question containing WTD 152270_180921_Thankyou_WTD.pdf

Comment: Please edit your question and add the remaining filenames

Comment: Fixed, again sorry - I had misread/misapplied the rules for WTD / FWR - https://regex101.com/r/YrMoDN/2

Comment: Thankyou so much Corion! I just updated the question, I added some wildcard file names (with some info that needs deleting), also asked if the date format can be changed.

Comment: Please can you update the code with amended results, as updated in the question: ( removed "_1"  from  the converted filenames ending in "EIC_1")

Comment: Ok updated question to make the remaining requests more logical.

Comment: Ah, so your rules still are somewhat weird. But if you just want to rename `EIC_1` to `EIC`, that certainly can't be a problem now, right? If you have junk after `.pdf`, please clean that up - I won't write a regular expression for that either. Removing the stuff in parentheses is something I'll add soonish to the answer.

Comment: Corion you are a god to me! How do I approve your answer and most excellent help, I clicked the green tick?

Comment: Hi, this works PERFECT using the regex in 'A better finder replace' (ABFR) on a MAC. But on windows it doesnt work. Thing is ABFR is up to version 10 on a MAC with full Regex support. But on Windows the ABFR software is only on version 6! - I've been looking for an alternative software for windows but cant seem to find one that will run the script. I have one (advancedrenamer) that allows regex but has a script box to add code but and allows multi steps but is in the form of 1 script per step and shows the custom area between "function (index, item){}"